# How to delete files from "Manage files which have no checked in version" using powershell

Tags: powershell, content-type, file, check-in

I tried to delete custom content type from Pages library but got an exception `"content type is still in use"`. The I get to know that files should also be deleted from `"Manage files which have no checked in version`" in order to delete content type from Pages library.

How I can perform this step using powershell, any code hint can help me?

Comment: You would need to follow the same process as the UI, take ownership of them so they are checked out to you, then delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear-host

$web = get-spweb http://yourwebsite
$list = $web.Lists["your list"]

#get checked out files that have no major version
$checkedOutFiles = $list.CheckedOutFiles | ?{$_.Versions.Count -eq 0}

write-host ("Found "  + $checkedOutFiles.Count + " file(s)!")

foreach($file in $checkedOutFiles)
{
    write-host ("Parsing file: " + $file.LeafName)
    $file.TakeOverCheckOut()
    #deleting!
    $list.GetItemById($file.ListItemId).Recycle() | Out-Null    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

He developed a short little set of PowerShell Functions that can take ownership of the files, then recursively check in all files that are being checked out by the system account.
tryt his

```
#Add SharePoint Snapin if not using SharePoint's PowerShell Console
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
#First function takes ownerhip of all unmanaged files with no version
function Take-Ownership{
param(
$spSite,
$spList
)
$site = Get-SPWeb -Identity $spSite
$list = $site.Lists[$spList]

$list.CheckedOutFiles | ForEach-Object{
$_.LeafName+ " had it's ownership taken from: "+$_.CheckedOutBy.DisplayName+"`n"
$_.TakeOverCheckOut()
}
}
#This Function takes a folder object and recursively checks in
#all files which are checked out by the System Account
function checkin-AllFiles{
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]
$currFolder
)

$currFolder.Files | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.CheckedOutByUser.UserLogin -eq "SHAREPOINT\system"){
$_.CheckIn("File checked in by administrator")
$_.Name+" has been checked in`n"
}
}
$currFolder.SubFolders| ForEach-Object{
checkin-AllFiles -currFolder $_
}
}
#This function basically combines the previous 2 for primary use
function Checkin-AllUnmanagedFiles{
param(
$site,
$library
)
$spSite = Get-SPWeb -identity $site
$spFolder = $spSite.Folders[$library]

Get-Date
"Taking ownership of the following Files`n"
Take-Ownership -spSite $site -spList $library
"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------`n"

    Get-Date
"Checking in the following files`n"
checkin-AllFiles -currFolder $spFolder
Get-Date
}
```

https://brenthafnersblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/manage-files-which-have-no-checked-in-version-list-larger-than-list-view-threshold/